# CakePHP 3: Empty result set returned while database has rows for same query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on limiting number of rows returned by a specific query to ones that have been modified within last 30 days using column `modified`. The code for this selection goes like this:

```
            $conditions = ['Models.receiver'   => $Model->receiver,
                           'Models.status IN'  => [40, 50],
                           //'Models.modified >' => 'NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY'
            ];
            $options = [
                'limit'      => 1,
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'order'      => ['Models.modified' => 'DESC']
            ];
            $result = $this->Models->find('all', $options)->first();
            debug($this->Models->find('all', $options));
```

The raw query when executed on MySQL command line prompt, without limitation by date on column `modified`, gives me following output:

```
SELECT
     receiver,
     status,
     modified
FROM
    printouts
WHERE
    receiver = (INT) X AND
    status IN (40, 50)
ORDER BY
    modified DESC LIMIT 1;

+----------+--------+---------------------+
| receiver | status | modified            |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  (INT) X |     50 | 2016-11-21 05:33:02 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The corresponding result set received in CakePHP 3 Controller is also correct:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Model) {

    'receiver' => (int) X,
    'status' => (int) 50,
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

            'time' => '2016-11-21T05:33:02+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
            //... removed
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Models'

}
```

The query received from debugger is mentioned here:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

    '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
    'sql' => 'SELECT Models.receiver AS `Models__receiver`, Models.status AS `Models__status` Models.modified AS `Models__modified` FROM models Models WHERE (Models.receiver = :c0 AND Models.status in (:c1,:c2)) ORDER BY Models.modified DESC LIMIT 1', // extra columns have been removed for simplicity
    'params' => [
            ':c0' => [
                    'value' => (int) X,
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'placeholder' => 'c0'
            ],  
            ':c1' => [
                    'value' => (int) 40, 
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'placeholder' => 'c1'
            ],  
            ':c2' => [
                    'value' => (int) 50, 
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'placeholder' => 'c2'
            ]   
    ],
    // .... more details
}
```

Now, I rerun the same query with limitation on modified column, by uncommenting this line:

```
'Printouts.modified >' => 'NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY'
```

This time I receive an empty result set. The `$result` variable is set to `null` in the following line:

```
$result = $this->Models->find('all', $options)->first();
```

The raw query output still remains the same on MySQL command line prompt:

```
SELECT
    receiver,
    status,
    modified
FROM
    printouts
WHERE
    receiver = (int) X AND
    status IN (40, 50) AND
    MODIFIED > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
ORDER BY
    modified DESC LIMIT 1;
+----------+--------+---------------------+
| receiver | status | modified            |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  (int) X |     50 | 2016-11-21 05:33:02 |
+----------+--------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

On debugging the same query object this time, I receive following SQL:

```
object(Cake\ORM\Query) {

    '(help)' => 'This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it.',
    'sql' => 'SELECT Models.receiver AS `Models__receiver`, Models.status AS `Models__status`, Models.modified AS `Models__modified` FROM models Models WHERE (Models.receiver = :c0 AND Models.status in (:c1,:c2) AND Models.modified > :c3) ORDER BY Models.modified DESC LIMIT 1',
    'params' => [
            ':c0' => [
                    'value' => (int) X,
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'placeholder' => 'c0'
            ],
            ':c1' => [
                    'value' => (int) 40,
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'placeholder' => 'c1'
            ],
            ':c2' => [
                    'value' => (int) 50,
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'placeholder' => 'c2'
            ],
            ':c3' => [
                    'value' => 'NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY',
                    'type' => 'datetime',
                    'placeholder' => 'c3'
            ]
    ],
}
```

Assume value of `X` to be integer and same at all times. `Model` is a placeholder name.

How do I identify the gap in the two query executions and remove the difference in order achieve my initial objective of limiting rows by datetime stored in column `modified`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `'Printouts.modified >' => 'NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY'`, you are telling it to look for columns where the modified date is greater than the literal string `'NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY'`. Try `'Printouts.modified > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY'` instead.